# Dreamveawer not showing preview (empty page)

Tags: html, css, dreamweaver

I've downloaded full calendar from [here](https://github.com/arshaw/fullcalendar/releases/download/v2.9.1/fullcalendar-2.9.1.zip). Then I've added site to dreamveawer, with root folder being fullcalendar-2.9.1. I wanted to work on demos inside this folder, but dreamveawer is showing empty page when I am opening demo sites. If I pick preview in browser, than page displays normally. Only inside dreamveawer I see only white screen.

First picture: site that I created 
Second picture: code - design view of one of demo pages

[image: Created site Calendar]

[image: Design area is empty]

Comment: did you set up a local host on your machine and configure it within dreamweaver? you'll need it as full callendar has php files which are required to run.

Comment: follow this to set and configure your localhost, this is using wordpress but it's the same process. [WPtricks local host](http://wptricks.co.uk/edit-wordpress-with-dreamweaver-using-a-local-server/#.V7WCh46Z2EI)

Comment: @Aaron - thanks for answer. I was planning to use this plugin on .net application. Will this be possible if full calendar is using php?

Comment: I'm affraid i know nothing about .net apps

Comment: Can you post your answer? I would like to mark it as solution.

Comment: Thanks @FrenkyB i've added my answer below :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to run php script through without a local server.

You'll need to add one to your system (perhaps xxamp or wamp) and configure your localhost with dreamweaver. You'll find a tutorial on adding localhost to dreamweaver here [WPTricks adding localhost](http://wptricks.co.uk/edit-wordpress-with-dreamweaver-using-a-local-server/#.V7WCh46Z2EI), It's using wordpress in the example but with remain the same for your setting inside dreamweaver.